# UITableView and async image url calls

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, asynchronous

I have a question: don't know whether its bad design or I just need some code.

- I have a UITableView
- I async load images from my server into a NSMutableDictionary as
  cache and load it in the cell

My problem is, if I have a lot of cells and quickly scroll through, my cell image will load the the images **"in line"** because they are async gutted and doesn't know that the cell has been reused.

**Should I:**

- Cancel the API call? How do I do this easily? I am just using NSData
  dataWithContentsOfURL in a async block
- Detect if the cell isnt there anymore? How do I do this? The cell I
  reused

Looking forward to hear your input!

Regards,
Nam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked:

> [Should I] cancel the API call? How do I do this easily? I am just using `NSData dataWithContentsOfURL` in a async block

Yes, you probably do want to cancel it, but unfortunately `dataWithContentsOfURL` is not a cancelable request.

You'd presumably want to retrieve the image using a cancelable mechanism. For example, you can use `NSURLSession` with `dataTaskWithURL`, which will return a `NSURLSessionTask` object, which you can `cancel` whenever you need. If using `NSURLConnection` (i.e. if supporting iOS versions prior to 7.0), then you have to use delegate-based rendition of `NSURLConnection`, which is also cancelable.

> Detect if the cell isnt there anymore? How do I do this? The cell [may be] reused.

You can either

- cancel the request when your table view's `didEndDisplayingCell` is called (in iOS 6.0 and later);
- when your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is configuring cell, you can cancel any prior requests for that cell;
- your completion block that is updating the cell asynchronously should check if the cell is still visible (by calling `[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]`, a table view method that confirms whether the cell for that `NSIndexPath` is still visible; note, this `UITableView` method should not be confused with the very similarly named `UITableViewDataSource` protocol method).

---

Note, there are classes out there that solve this problem for you. Take a look at `UIImageView` categories in [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) or [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage). These both gracefully do asynchronous image retrieval, and if the image view is reused, the prior request is canceled.

Comment: So, I marked this one as the answer since it seems like the most right thing to do. SDWebImage seems like the right way, but I'm using MWPhotoBrowser which using an old version on SDWebImage and I don't know how update it.

Answer (score 0):

There's a delegate method of `UITableView`, `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndDisplayingCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {...}` you can cancel any on going requests or modify cell objects here.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndDisplayingCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
    [self cancelOnGoingRequest];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it may help in my case i used lazy loading classes to load 10 images (for 10 cell) by async call and set the images in the custom design cell's imageview and when user scroll down then again lazy loading class is called to invoke with page number and it is working fine so you may use it.

Answer (score 0):

Just posting this as a comment on what I did.

I decided to keeping my code and kept a local cache. I'm saving all the images in a dictionary with the url as key. To avoid the imageview loading the images multiple times (due to the cel being reused) I added a random tag to the imageview before the async call and checked if the imageview has the same tag when the image is downloaded (and saved in the dictionary).

If you have any comments or this is a bad design, please let me know.

Thanks!